# How to resize the child node fit inside SKSpriteNode when resizing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am creating a virtual gamepad for my game, It has one main SKSpriteNode with circle image and four child node(up, down, left, right) with image. When I am using default size for all it looks perfect but it's big in size and when I tried to resize the main circle SKSpriteNode all it's child node are bigger then it's parent and I am unable to calculate size for child node that will fit for every condition(different size of Main node).

```
-(id)initWithJoystickImage:(NSString *)baseImage
                   upImage:(NSString *)upImage downImage:(NSString *)downImage leftImage:(NSString *)leftImage rightImage:(NSString *)rightImage
{
    if((self = [super initWithImageNamed:baseImage]))
    {
        SKSpriteNode *up = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:upImage];
        up.position = CGPointMake(0, up.frame.size.height/2);
        [self addChild:up];

        SKSpriteNode *down = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:downImage];
        down.position = CGPointMake(0, -down.frame.size.height/2);
        [self addChild:down];

        SKSpriteNode *right = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:rightImage];
        right.position = CGPointMake(right.frame.size.width/2, 0);
self.size.height/2.5);
        [self addChild:right];

        SKSpriteNode *left = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:leftImage];
        left.position = CGPointMake(-left.frame.size.width/2, 0);
 self.size.height/2.5);
        [self addChild:left];
    }
    return self;
}
```

[image: Default size]

When using default size

[image: When resize]

when resize according to device size

**Edit 1: adding joystick and resize code**

```
Joystick *joystick = [[Joystick alloc] initWithJoystickImage:@"cricle.png" upImage:@"up.png" downImage:@"down.png" leftImage:@"left.png" rightImage:@"right.png"];
    joystick.size=CGSizeMake(DeviceHeight/3, DeviceHeight/3);
    joystick.position=CGPointMake(DeviceWidth/2-joystick.frame.size.width/2, -DeviceHeight/2+joystick.frame.size.height/2);
```

Comment: How do you resize your node? `[SKAction scaleTo]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only change the size of the parent node (`joystick`). This will resize your parent and child nodes together:

```
[joystick runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:2.0/3.0 duration:0.0]];  // Change scale value
```

Comment: `scaleTo:2/3` didn't work but `scaleTo:.5` did work but when scaling its position also changes , I don't want that

Comment: @VarunNaharia My fault, the scale should be a float number. Have you changed the anchor point of the joystick? If the anchor point is (0.5, 0.5), it will be scaled from the center, so the position won't be changed.